# SSRS: Subreport Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS dashboard with a main-report and 2 sub-reports. I have 6 parameters to select from.. One of the parameter is 'Division'.

The main report works fine except for only one of the 'Division ID', but when you hard-code that 'Division ID', it works perfect. Besides, If I ran that 'Division ID' from the 'Main Report' it throws 'Error: Subreport could not be shown.'

Did anyone of you solve the similar issue? I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix, for some reason SSRS considers that particular 'Division ID' as 'Integer' even after having it set to 'Varchar'. So I had to use the below SSRS expression to convert Integer to String and it worked perfect!

=IIF(CStr(Fields!DataField.Value),CStr(Fields!DataField.Value),"##")

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are two things I can think of to check:

**Parameter Name**

In your first paragraph, the parameter name is 'Division'; in the remaining paragraphs, it is 'Division ID'. Is the name consistent wherever the parameter is used?

**Subreport Parameter Reference**

Right-click your subreport and choose "Subreport Properties", then "Parameters" (if editing the report in BIDS). Click the "*f*x" symbol next to the Division ID parameter and make sure it's being referenced as expected. For example, this is from a subreport referencing a field value on the main report:

```
=Fields!DivisionId.Value
```

Hopefully one of these will help!

Comment: Sorry I should have been more elaborative: 'Division' is the parameter's name and 'Division ID' is the value field. I think that's fine with what is it now..